# Can't NPM install SQLite3 in node 6.x

Tags: node.js, sqlite, npm

I've been doing a lot of research but am coming up empty here.  it's a big long ugly IMO.  I can definitely browse to and successfully download that tar.gz first referenced in the error.  All my other NPM installs runs fine.  Im not a big fan of SQLite3 but I have a project I worked on that I need to demo for some coworkers.  Any help getting this to install would greatly appreciated.

> sqlite3@3.1.6 install C:\WS\linked10\linkedout\node_modules\sqlite3
>   node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download:
>   https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com
>   /sqlite3/v3.1.6/node-v48-win32-x64.tar.gz node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built
>   binaries not found for sqlite3@3.1.6 and node@6.7.0 (node-v48 ABI)
>   (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
>
> C:\WS\linked10\linkedout\node_modules\sqlite3>if not defined
>   npm_config_node_gyp  (node "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_mo
>   dules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" clean )  else (node "" clean )
>
> C:\WS\linked10\linkedout\node_modules\sqlite3>if not defined
>   npm_config_node_gyp  (node "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_mo
>   dules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" configure --fallback-to-build
>   --module=C:\WS\lin ked10\linkedout\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64\node_sqlite3
>   .node --module_name=node_sqlite3
>   --module_path=C:\WS\linked10\linkedout\node_mod ules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64 )  else (node "" configure
>   --fallbac k-to-build --module=C:\WS\linked10\linkedout\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\no de-v48-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3
>   --module_path=C:\W S\linked10\linkedout\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64
>   ) gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python
>   executable "python", you can set the PYT HON env variable. gyp ERR!
>   stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\nod
>   e_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:401:14) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
>   -gyp\lib\configure.js:356:11 gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15) gyp ERR! System Windows_NT
>   6.1.7601 gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodej
>   s\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   "configure" "--f allback-to-build"
>   "--module=C:\WS\linked10\linkedout\node_modules\sqlite3\
>   lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node"
>   "--module_name=node_sqlite3 "
>   "--module_path=C:\WS\linked10\linkedout\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\bindin
>   g\node-v48-win32-x64" gyp ERR! cwd
>   C:\WS\linked10\linkedout\node_modules\sqlite3 gyp ERR! node -v v6.7.0
>   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1 gyp ERR! not ok node-pre-gyp ERR! build
>   error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd
>   configure --fallb ack-to-build
>   --module=C:\WS\linked10\linkedout\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\ node-v48-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3
>   --module_path=C: \WS\linked10\linkedout\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-x64'
>   (1) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.
>   (C:\WS\linked10\linkedou
>   t\node_modules\sqlite3\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) node-pre-gyp
>   ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7) node-pre-gyp
>   ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
>   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/chi ld_process.js:226:5) node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT
>   6.1.7601 node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\WS\linked1
>   0\linkedout\node_modules\sqlite3\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-g
>   yp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd
>   C:\WS\linked10\linkedout\node_modules\sqlite3 node-pre-gyp ERR! node
>   -v v6.7.0 node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.30 node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

Comment: did you try to download https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com /sqlite3/v3.1.6/node-v48-win32-x64.tar.gz in your browser. My guess is that .tar.gz is being blocked. If you can access the internet without the corporate proxy it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had a hunch there was an issue with browser exception of some kind.  My company has an enforcement policy for IE browsers only.  AS a developer you can get put on a browser exception list which allows you to use chrome and firefox.  I got added to the list and now the installs for SQLite3 works perfectly.  I assume there is some kind of browser spoofing or something happening to download the files it needs but Im not entirely sure.  These are my other NPM setting to successfully function within our corp network using NPM.

```
npm set proxy=http://my.proxy
npm set https-proxy=http://my.corp.proxy
npm set user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 9.0; en-US)"
npm config set strict-ssl false
npm config set registry http://my.corp.npmrepo/path/
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no pre-built binaries, node tries to build it from sources.
Your error:

**Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT HON env variable.**

Read Installation notes for this module: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp

Comment: So I don't think my issue has anything to do with Python being on my machine but I went ahead and installed it.  I got ride of that error but didn't resolve my issue.  I may have an internal issue behind my corporate networks firewall.  I've got NPM working in general but for this SQLite install, I think there is something additional it is trying to do.  I may need to be added to a browser exception list for this fallback install process to happen.

Comment: As i can see your OS is Windows. For native addons compilation on windows you should have installed, according to node-gyp: Visual C++ Build Tools, Visual Studio 2015. And correct configuration. If you have all this products installed already post new error log, after python installation, and i will try to help you.